# R: Generating sparse matrix with all elements as rows and columns

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a data set with user to user. It doesn't have all users as col and row. For example,

```
 U1      U2     T
  1      3      1
  1      6      1
  2      4      1
  3      5      1
```

u1 and u2 represent users of the dataset. When I create a sparse matrix using following code, (df- keep all data of above dataset as a dataframe)

```
trustmatrix <- xtabs(T~U1+U2,df,sparse = TRUE)  

   3  4  5  6
1  1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  1  0
```

Because this matrix doesn't have all the users in row and columns as below.

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6
1  0  0  1  0  0  1
2  0  0  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0 
5  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

If I want to get above matrix after sparse matrix, How can I do so in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the columns to `factor` with `levels` as 1 through 6 and then use `xtabs`

```
df1[1:2] <- lapply(df1[1:2], factor, levels = 1:6)
as.matrix(xtabs(T~U1+U2,df1,sparse = TRUE))
#   U2
#U1  1 2 3 4 5 6
#  1 0 0 1 0 0 1
#  2 0 0 0 1 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 0 1 0
#  4 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  5 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  6 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or another option is to get the expanded index filled with 0s and then use `sparseMatrix`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Matrix)
df2 <- crossing(U1 = 1:6, U2 = 1:6) %>% 
          left_join(df1) %>% 
          mutate(T = replace(T, is.na(T), 0))
sparseMatrix(i = df2$U1, j = df2$U2, x = df2$T)
```

Or use `spread`

```
spread(df2, U2, T)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. The first answer works perfectly. I am still wondering how factor works in R. I couldn't understand the other two methods. Is there any extra package need for crossing function?

Comment: @Anu The crossing is from `tidyr` which is one of the packages in `tidyverse`.  Factor with `levels` specified will make sure that those levels that doesn't have any value will not be dropped off.  The second method is creating the full combinations with `crossing` and then do a left_join with the original dataset and replace the NA values with 0, and then spread to wide format